# How to call Several Sheets from a spreadsheet faster and use them inside if statements

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a script that duplicates a Spreadsheet then deletes/hides some of its sheets based of some checkboxes from the initial sheet.

I am calling many sheets and using them inside if statements. Depending on the checkboxes, specific sheets will be removed or hidden.

Is there a faster way to execute this ?

Here's the script:

```
        function template() {

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();  
  var campaigninfosheet = ss.getSheetByName('Campaign Info');
    
      var spreadsheettemplateId = "INSERT SPREADSHEET ID";
      var spreadsheettemplate = DriveApp.getFileById(spreadsheettemplateId);
      var spreadsheetcopy = spreadsheettemplate.makeCopy();
      var spreadsheetcopyID = spreadsheetcopy.getId();
      var sheetcopy = SpreadsheetApp.openById(spreadsheetcopyID);
      var fileName = sheetcopy.getName();
    
      var awarenesscheckbox = campaigninfosheet.getRange("A2:B2").getValues()
      var videoviewscheckbox = campaigninfosheet.getRange("A3:B3").getValues()
      var engagementscheckbox = campaigninfosheet.getRange("A4:B4").getValues()
      var followerscheckbox = campaigninfosheet.getRange("A5:B5").getValues() 
      var trafficcheckbox = campaigninfosheet.getRange("A6:B6").getValues()
      var appinstallscheckbox = campaigninfosheet.getRange("A7:B7").getValues()
      var leadgenerationcheckbox = campaigninfosheet.getRange("A8:B8").getValues()
      var conversionscheckbox = campaigninfosheet.getRange("A9:B9").getValues()
    
      var metaplatform = campaigninfosheet.getRange("C2:D2").getValues();
      var snapplatform = campaigninfosheet.getRange("C3:D3").getValues();
      var tiktokplatform = campaigninfosheet.getRange("C4:D4").getValues();
      var twitterplatform = campaigninfosheet.getRange("C5:D5").getValues();
      var youtubeplatform = campaigninfosheet.getRange("C6:D6").getValues();
      var googleplatform = campaigninfosheet.getRange("C7:D7").getValues();
      var linkedinplatform = campaigninfosheet.getRange("C8:D8").getValues();
      var programmaticplatform = campaigninfosheet.getRange("C9:D9").getValues(); 
    
    
    
          for (var i = 0; i < awarenesscheckbox.length; i++) {
        
            var metaawarenesscsheet = sheetcopy.getSheetByName('Meta Awareness Campaign');
            var metaawarenessassheet = sheetcopy.getSheetByName('Meta Awareness Ad Set');
            var fbawarenessassheet = sheetcopy.getSheetByName('FB Awareness Ad Set')
            var igawarenessassheet = sheetcopy.getSheetByName('IG Awareness Ad Set')
            var snapchatawarenesscsheet = sheetcopy.getSheetByName('Snapchat Awareness Campaign');
            var snapchatawarenessassheet = sheetcopy.getSheetByName('Snapchat Awareness Ad Set');
            var tiktokawarenesscsheet = sheetcopy.getSheetByName('TikTok Awareness Campaign');
            var tiktokawarenessassheet = sheetcopy.getSheetByName('TikTok Awareness Ad Set');
            var twitterawarenesscsheet = sheetcopy.getSheetByName('Twitter Awareness Campaign');
            var twitterawarenessassheet = sheetcopy.getSheetByName('Twitter Awareness Ad Set');
            var youtubeawarenesscsheet = sheetcopy.getSheetByName('Youtube Awareness Campaign');
            var youtubeawarenessassheet = sheetcopy.getSheetByName('Youtube Awareness Ad Set');
            var googleawarenesscsheet = sheetcopy.getSheetByName('Google Awareness Campaign');
            var googleawarenessassheet = sheetcopy.getSheetByName('Google Awareness Ad Set');
            var linkedinawarenesscsheet = sheetcopy.getSheetByName('LinkedIn Awareness Campaign');
            var linkedinawarenessassheet = sheetcopy.getSheetByName('LinkedIn Awareness Ad Set');
            var programmaticawarenesscsheet = sheetcopy.getSheetByName('Programmatic Awareness Campaign');
            var programmaticawarenessassheet = sheetcopy.getSheetByName('Programmatic Awareness Ad Set');
            var awarenesssheets = [metaawarenesscsheet, metaawarenessassheet, fbawarenessassheet, igawarenessassheet, snapchatawarenesscsheet, snapchatawarenessassheet, tiktokawarenesscsheet, tiktokawarenessassheet, twitterawarenesscsheet, twitterawarenessassheet, youtubeawarenesscsheet, youtubeawarenessassheet, googleawarenesscsheet, googleawarenessassheet, linkedinawarenesscsheet, linkedinawarenessassheet, programmaticawarenesscsheet, programmaticawarenessassheet]
        
            if (awarenesscheckbox[i][0] === "N") {
        
              awarenesssheets.forEach(asheet => sheetcopy.deleteSheet(asheet))
            }
        
            else if (awarenesscheckbox[i][0] === "Y") {
              for (var i = 0; i < metaplatform.length; i++) {
                if (metaplatform[i][0] === "Y") {
                  [metaawarenesscsheet, metaawarenessassheet, fbawarenessassheet, igawarenessassheet].forEach(metaasheet => metaasheet.hideSheet())
                }
                else {
                  [metaawarenesscsheet, metaawarenessassheet, fbawarenessassheet, igawarenessassheet].forEach(metaasheet => sheetcopy.deleteSheet(metaasheet))
                }
              }
 for (var i = 0; i < snapplatform.length; i++) {
        if (snapplatform[i][0] === "Y") {

          [snapchatawarenesscsheet, snapchatawarenessassheet].forEach(snapasheet => snapasheet.hideSheet())
        }
        else if (snapplatform[i][0] === "N") {
          [snapchatawarenesscsheet, snapchatawarenessassheet].forEach(snapasheet => sheetcopy.deleteSheet(snapasheet))
        }
      }
      for (var i = 0; i < tiktokplatform.length; i++) {
        if (tiktokplatform[i][0] === "Y") {

          [tiktokawarenesscsheet, tiktokawarenessassheet].forEach(tiktokasheet => tiktokasheet.hideSheet())
        }
        else {
          [tiktokawarenesscsheet, tiktokawarenessassheet].forEach(tiktokasheet => sheetcopy.deleteSheet(tiktokasheet))
        }
      }

      for (var i = 0; i < twitterplatform.length; i++) {
        if (twitterplatform[i][0] === "Y") {

          [twitterawarenesscsheet, twitterawarenessassheet].forEach(twitterasheet => twitterasheet.hideSheet())
        }
        else {
          [twitterawarenesscsheet, twitterawarenessassheet].forEach(twitterasheet => sheetcopy.deleteSheet(twitterasheet))
        }
      }

      for (var i = 0; i < youtubeplatform.length; i++) {
        if (youtubeplatform[i][0] === "Y") {

          [youtubeawarenesscsheet, youtubeawarenessassheet].forEach(youtubeasheet => youtubeasheet.hideSheet())
        }
        else {
          [youtubeawarenesscsheet, youtubeawarenessassheet].forEach(youtubeasheet => sheetcopy.deleteSheet(youtubeasheet))
        }
      }

      for (var i = 0; i < googleplatform.length; i++) {
        if (googleplatform[i][0] === "Y") {

          [googleawarenesscsheet, googleawarenessassheet].forEach(googleasheet => googleasheet.hideSheet())
        }
        else {
          [googleawarenesscsheet, googleawarenessassheet].forEach(googleasheet => sheetcopy.deleteSheet(googleasheet))
        }
      }

      for (var i = 0; i < linkedinplatform.length; i++) {
        if (linkedinplatform[i][0] === "Y") {

          [linkedinawarenesscsheet, linkedinawarenessassheet].forEach(linkedinasheet => linkedinasheet.hideSheet())
        }
        else {
          [linkedinawarenesscsheet, linkedinawarenessassheet].forEach(linkedinasheet => sheetcopy.deleteSheet(linkedinasheet))
        }
      }

      for (var i = 0; i < programmaticplatform.length; i++) {
        if (programmaticplatform[i][0] === "Y") {

          [programmaticawarenesscsheet, programmaticawarenessassheet].forEach(programmaticasheet => programmaticasheet.hideSheet())
        }
        else {
          [programmaticawarenesscsheet, programmaticawarenessassheet].forEach(programmaticasheet => sheetcopy.deleteSheet(programmaticasheet))
        }
      }
    }
  }
        }
```

Comment: `videoviewscheckbox` through to `conversionscheckbox` never seem to be referenced after the initial `getValues`.

Comment: Each `getValues` range consists of two adjacent cells which are then referenced in `for ` statements (e.g. `metaplatform.length` followed by `googleplatform[i][0]`). At there actually two values in those ranges, or is it a merged cell? I'm wondering how many `for` statements are REALLY required? I'm also wondering whether you could just get the column with a single `getValues`, though the current approach does make the code easier to understand.

Comment: Would help if you could attach a screenshot or example sheet. Additionally, it appears you don't have checkboxes but are rather checking values of cells. I have a pretty solid solution for you but just need more information.

Comment: Hello and thank you for your assistance. Here's the sample spreadsheet, the checkboxes are in the first sheet called "Campaign info" as well as all the references https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1NVD6lG5lM1G7yx06l2EqAg49fJB9jKDkUd1G52Z4KYA/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: I have edited the link for the spreadsheet in my previous reply. Thank you again for your kind assistance

Comment: @Karim So here's what I gather: You are using the checkboxes to include those platforms with their related objective sheets. If a platform checkbox is not checked, those related platform sheets should not be included. If a objective checkbox is not checked, those related objective sheets should not be included. If a platform sheet is checked, and an objective sheet is checked, that related platform objective sheet should be included but hidden. Does that sound correct?

Comment: @NEWAZA 100% correct

Comment: @Karim Debugging now, should be a few more minutes

Comment: @NEWAZA Take your time. Thank you for your kind assistance I highly appreciate it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try this:**

```
function myFunction() {

  const NewSpreadsheetTitle = `New Spreadsheet Title`

  //

  const MASTER = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()

  const SHEETS = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets()
  const INFOSHEET = MASTER.getSheetByName(`Campaign Info`)

  //

  const PLATFORMS = INFOSHEET.getRange(`C2:D9`)
                             .getValues()
                             .filter(Row => Row[0] === `Y`)
                             .flatMap(Row => Row[1])

  const OBJECTIVES = INFOSHEET.getRange(`A2:B9`)
                              .getValues()
                              .filter(Row => Row[0] === `Y`)
                              .flatMap(Row => Row[1])

  //

  const COPY = SpreadsheetApp.create(NewSpreadsheetTitle)

  INFOSHEET.copyTo(COPY).setName(`Campaign Info`)
  MASTER.getSheetByName(`Overall`).copyTo(COPY).setName(`Overall`)
  
  PLATFORMS.forEach(Platform => {
    SHEETS.filter(Sheet => Sheet.getName().includes(Platform))
          .forEach(Sheet => {
            if (Sheet.getName() === Platform) Sheet.copyTo(COPY).setName(Sheet.getName())
            if (OBJECTIVES.some(Objective => Sheet.getName().includes(Objective))) Sheet.copyTo(COPY).hideSheet().setName(Sheet.getName())
          })
  })
                
}
```

**Commented:**

```
function myFunctionCommented() {

  // Title of New Spreadsheet being created below.
  const NewSpreadsheetTitle = `New Spreadsheet Title`


  const MASTER = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()

  // Creates an array of all Sheets in Spreadsheet.
  const SHEETS = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets()
  const INFOSHEET = MASTER.getSheetByName(`Campaign Info`)

  
  // With the Range of `C2:D9`..
  const PLATFORMS = INFOSHEET.getRange(`C2:D9`)
                             // Get values..
                             .getValues()
                             // Keep only checked boxes..
                             .filter(Row => Row[0] === `Y`)
                             // And create an array of only the platforms.
                             .flatMap(Row => Row[1])

  const OBJECTIVES = INFOSHEET.getRange(`A2:B9`)
                              .getValues()
                              .filter(Row => Row[0] === `Y`)
                              .flatMap(Row => Row[1])

  // Create a new spreadsheet..
  const COPY = SpreadsheetApp.create(NewSpreadsheetTitle)

  // and copy over Campaign Info and Overall.
  INFOSHEET.copyTo(COPY).setName(`Campaign Info`)
  MASTER.getSheetByName(`Overall`).copyTo(COPY).setName(`Overall`)
  
  // For each platform:
  PLATFORMS.forEach(Platform => {
    // Get all sheets that include the current platform in their name.
    SHEETS.filter(Sheet => Sheet.getName().includes(Platform))
          // For each of these filtered sheets:
          .forEach(Sheet => {
            // If the sheet's name is the platform, copy it over.
            if (Sheet.getName() === Platform) Sheet.copyTo(COPY).setName(Sheet.getName())
            // If the sheet's name is the platform, copy it over but hide it.
            if (OBJECTIVES.some(Objective => Sheet.getName().includes(Objective))) Sheet.copyTo(COPY).hideSheet().setName(Sheet.getName())
          })
  })
                
}
```

Albeit, it runs rather slow due the amount of sheets and their contents.

I recommend creating a new folder and separating your template sheets by platform into their own Spreadsheets. You can then have your "Master" sheet contain just the Campaign Info and Overall sheet, and Apps Script code.

**Separate Sheet Method:**

```
const MASTERS = {

  Meta: `Spreadsheet ID Here`,
  Snapchat: `Spreadsheet ID Here`,
  TikTok: `Spreadsheet ID Here`,
  // etc
}

function VersionTwo() {

  const NewSpreadsheetTitle = `New Spreadsheet Title`

  //

  const MASTER = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
  const INFOSHEET = MASTER.getSheetByName(`Campaign Info`)
  const OVERALLSHEET = MASTER.getSheetByName(`Overall`)

  //

  const PLATFORMS = INFOSHEET.getRange(`C2:D9`)
                             .getValues()
                             .filter(Row => Row[0] === `Y`)
                             .flatMap(Row => Row[1])

  const OBJECTIVES = INFOSHEET.getRange(`A2:B9`)
                              .getValues()
                              .filter(Row => Row[0] === `Y`)
                              .flatMap(Row => Row[1])

  //

  const CLONE = SpreadsheetApp.create(NewSpreadsheetTitle)
  INFOSHEET.copyTo(COPY).setName(`Campaign Info`)
  OVERALLSHEET.copyTo(COPY).setName(`Overall`)
  
  PLATFORMS.forEach(Platform => {
    SpreadsheetApp.openById(MASTERS[Platform])
                  .getSheets()
                  .filter(Sheet => Sheet.getName().includes(Platform))
                  .forEach(Sheet => {
                    if (Sheet.getName() === Platform) Sheet.copyTo(CLONE).setName(Sheet.getName())
                    if (OBJECTIVES.some(Objective => Sheet.getName().includes(Objective))) Sheet.copyTo(CLONE).hideSheet().setName(Sheet.getName())
                  })
  })

}
```

Comment: Thank you for your input but it took the same amount of time to execute your code as mine. The problem is that I have to duplicate that spreadsheet instead of making a new copy because I have to import additional code which I haven't showed in the sample spreadsheet. I will mark the answer as answered because it seems there isn't a faster way to execute this. Thank you again for your time and amazing explanation!

Comment: I would be curious if you tried the second method if it would be faster for you; I do think the bulkiness of the spreadsheet is slowing things down quite a bit. In regards to including code in the new spreadsheet, you most likely can perform it from the master sheet. Let me know!

Comment: Thank you for again for taking your time to check my case. The additional code generates a Google Slides report based on the data so it must be taken from that duplicated template. It will be used by my employees so using the code from the Master Spreadsheet will not be a possibilty unfortunately. But at least your code showed me that this is the best we can achieve in terms of speed with such a spreadsheet

Comment: Last thought would be to still try splitting the sheets, and instead of `const CLONE = SpreadsheetApp.create(NewSpreadsheetTitle)`, replace that with cloning your Master sheet of only Campaign Info, Overall and all additional code and use the second method above. Best of luck!

Comment: On a second thought, splitting the spreadsheet to several would actually be a pretty good idea. If my other reporting code relies on the sheets, will it make it slower to take the information from several spreadsheets instead of 1 ?

Comment: Could you clarify "other reporting code" a little further?

Comment: I have another code linked to the spreadsheet that generates a Google Slide based of the data from the spreadsheet. Depending on the platforms and objectives, it generates a presentation, presenting the data with charts and data taken from the spreadsheet. This Google Slide is also a duplicate from a template slide. Once duplicated, placeholders in it are replaced. So for ex, if Youtube Awareness exists in the data, the script will create a Youtube Awareness presentation based of the template, and the script then removes all unwanted slides from the duplicated slide

Comment: From what you described that shouldn't be an issue, depending on how you're checking if "<Platform> <Objective>" sheet data exists or not. Though, hypothetically, my above code's end-result is no different that your current code, the method to get there is just changed.

Comment: you gave me a good idea. I will try splitting the sheets only to duplicate the spreadsheet. I will let you know the results of this.

Comment: ok and yes I see your point. I will try splitting the sheets and give you feedback. I will also try your code and my code and let you know. Thanks again for your support, as well as the great idea 

Comment: hello, just wanted to let you know that your idea worked like a charm! Your script generated the template in under 3 mins VS. 7 mins previously. Million thx for this!

Comment: Hello, I hope you are doing well! Could you please have a look at my new question ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75962119/apps-script-if-a-condition-is-met-on-sheets-a-b-c-apply-an-action-on-sheets