# Apps Script : If a Condition is met on Sheets A,B,C , apply an action on Sheets X,Y,Z

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a Google Sheets script that sets a cell's background color in one sheet's cell if a condition is met in another sheet

If on "Client TDL" sheet the condition is met, it will change the background of the specified cell in "Client" sheet.

**Here's my code:**

```
    function tasks() {
var sh1 = ss.getSheetByName("Client TDL");
var sh4 = ss.getSheetByName("Client");
var tasks1 = sh1.getRange("A2:C11").getValues();

for (var i = 0; i < tasks1.length; i++) {
    if (tasks1[i][0] === 'Y')
    {       
      var sh1Tasks1 = sh4.createTextFinder(tasks1[i][2]).findNext().getCell(1,1).
      getA1Notation()                 

      sh4.getRange(sh1Tasks1).offset(0,1).setBackground('#d9ead3')
    } 
                                      
}
}
```

**What I want to achieve:**

Currently, the script works only on "Client" sheet and "Client TDL" sheet.

I want to apply this action on 2 groups of sheets. The first group is called "Client Name" sheets, the second group is called "Client Name TDL"

So I want each "Client Name TDL" sheet to apply the action on each of the respective "Client Name" sheet, if the condition is met.

For example, if client name is "X". It will have a sheet called "X", and another sheet called "X TDL". If the condition is met in "X TDL", it will action the change on sheet "X".

Knowing that the number of "Client TDL Sheets"/"Client Sheets" pair are dynamic, how can I write this in Apps Script ?

- This script should run through a button, so a simple trigger cannot do the job.
- `getActiveSheet()` cannot be used because I need to define both "Client" and "Client TDL" sheets.

Below is my modified script:

What I tried doing:

1. Define all sheets that contain the text "TDL"
2. Define all the sheets that exclude the text "TDL" **AND** include the client's name (this is because I have sheets in my spreadsheet that have other names, so I cannot **only** call sheets that exclude the text "TDL", otherwise those unwanted sheets will also be called.

The script executed but it didn't do anything.

**modified script :**

```
function tasksV2() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive()
  var sheets = ss.getSheets();
  var sh0 = sheets.filter(s => s.getSheetName().includes('TDL'));
  var clientsheetname = sh0.forEach(cs=>cs.getSheetName())
  var sh1 = sheets.filter(s => !s.getSheetName().includes('TDL') && s.getSheetName().includes(clientsheetname));
  sh0.forEach(s0=>{
    sh1.forEach(s1=>{
var tasks1 = s0.getRange("A2:C11").getValues();
var tasks2 = s0.getRange("D2:F11").getValues();
var tasks3 = s0.getRange("G2:I11").getValues();
var tasks4 = s0.getRange("J2:L11").getValues();
var tasks5 = s0.getRange("M2:O11").getValues();

for (var i = 0; i < tasks1.length; i++) {
    if (tasks1[i][0] === 'Y')
    {       
      var sh1Tasks1 = s1.createTextFinder(tasks1[i][2]).findNext().getCell(1,1).
      getA1Notation()                 

      s1.getRange(sh1Tasks1).offset(0,1).setBackground('#d9ead3')
    } 
                               
}    
  })   
  }) 
}
```

**Here's the sample spreadsheet:**
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1mhMsTCyjWMWWkUF6INk0_XulNTjZLks1GpVZzdVJkyg/edit#gid=0

Comment: Can I confirm that what you meant in `If on Sheet 1,2,3 the condition is met, I want it to change the background on Sheet 4,5,6` is that changes on 1 correspond to 4, 2 on 5, and 3 on 6? I have to make sure since you have not placed `respectively` in the statement. Also, please provide [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)  in the form of a sample spreadsheet wherein the script that you have provided works.

Comment: "What is the best approach to write this ?" There are many ways this could be written and you already have a working script for single set of sheets - why not just adapt this to your new goal? Have you tried to write a script to solve it? If so, would you please include that script in the question.

Comment: @PatrickdC hello and thank you for you kind assistance. Regarding your first question, yes that is correct. Changes on 1 correspond to 4, 2 on 5, and 3 on 6. Regarding the minimal reproducible example, you may find hereafter the link to the sample spreadsheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1mhMsTCyjWMWWkUF6INk0_XulNTjZLks1GpVZzdVJkyg/edit#gid=1974436256

Comment: @Tedinoz hello and thank you for your support. Unfortunately, I don't know how to do it. I have created a sample spreadsheet, I hope this helps with more clarity: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1mhMsTCyjWMWWkUF6INk0_XulNTjZLks1GpVZzdVJkyg/edit#gid=1974436256

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Suggestion: Assemble a JavaScript Object

I kept most of your working code and added a JavaScript Object to dynamically store all sheet names within the JSON object. Take note that this has the assumption of having pairs of pattarn Client 1 TLD' is to 'Client 1'.

### Script 1: One Button to Process One TLD Sheet

```
function amextdl() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

  //Step1: Assemble the JavaScript Object
  var listTDL = ss.getSheets().map(x => x.getName()).filter(y => y.match(/TDL/));
  var listNoTDL = listTDL.map(z => z.replace(' TDL', ''))
  var sheetsDictionary = listTDL.reduce((x, i, j) => {
    x[i] = listNoTDL[j];
    return x;
  }, {});

  //Step2: Access the key-value pair for the active sheet
  var sh0 = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var sh1 = ss.getSheetByName(sheetsDictionary[sh0.getName()]);

  //Step3: Process accordingly
  //from original script:
  var tasks1 = sh0.getRange("A2:C11").getValues();
  var tasks2 = sh0.getRange("D2:F11").getValues();
  var tasks3 = sh0.getRange("G2:I11").getValues();
  var tasks4 = sh0.getRange("J2:L11").getValues();
  var tasks5 = sh0.getRange("M2:O11").getValues();

  for (var i = 0; i < tasks1.length; i++) {
    if (tasks1[i][0] === 'Y') {
      var sh1Tasks1 = sh1.createTextFinder(tasks1[i][2]).findNext().getCell(1, 1).getA1Notation()
      sh1.getRange(sh1Tasks1).offset(0, 1).setBackground('#d9ead3')
    }

    if (tasks2[i][0] === 'Y') {
      var sh1Tasks2 = sh1.createTextFinder(tasks2[i][2]).findNext().getCell(1, 1).getA1Notation()
      sh1.getRange(sh1Tasks2).offset(0, 2).setBackground('#d9ead3')
    }

    if (tasks3[i][0] === 'Y') {
      var sh1Tasks3 = sh1.createTextFinder(tasks3[i][2]).findNext().getCell(1, 1).getA1Notation()
      sh1.getRange(sh1Tasks3).offset(0, 3).setBackground('#d9ead3')
    }
    if (tasks4[i][0] === 'Y') {
      var sh1Tasks4 = sh1.createTextFinder(tasks4[i][2]).findNext().getCell(1, 1).getA1Notation()
      sh1.getRange(sh1Tasks4).offset(0, 4).setBackground('#d9ead3')
    }
    if (tasks5[i][0] === 'Y') {
      var sh1Tasks5 = sh1.createTextFinder(tasks5[i][2]).findNext().getCell(1, 1).getA1Notation()
      sh1.getRange(sh1Tasks5).offset(0, 5).setBackground('#d9ead3')
    }
  }
}
```

### Script 2: One Button to Process All Sheets

```
function amextdl() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

  //Step 1: Group the sheet names into 2 different arrays
  var listTDL = ss.getSheets().map(x => x.getName()).filter(y => y.match(/TDL/));
  var listNoTDL = listTDL.map(z => z.replace(' TDL', ''));

  //Step 2: Assemble the JavaScript Object using the 2 arrays
  var sheetsDictionary = listTDL.reduce((x, i, j) => {
    x[i] = listNoTDL[j];
    return x;
  }, {});

  //Step3: Process accordingly by using map() on listTDL array
  listTDL.map(x => {
    var sh1 = ss.getSheetByName(sheetsDictionary[x]);

    //from original script:
    var tasks1 = ss.getSheetByName(x).getRange("A2:C11").getValues();
    var tasks2 = ss.getSheetByName(x).getRange("D2:F11").getValues();
    var tasks3 = ss.getSheetByName(x).getRange("G2:I11").getValues();
    var tasks4 = ss.getSheetByName(x).getRange("J2:L11").getValues();
    var tasks5 = ss.getSheetByName(x).getRange("M2:O11").getValues();

    for (var i = 0; i < tasks1.length; i++) {
      if (tasks1[i][0] === 'Y') {
        var sh1Tasks1 = sh1.createTextFinder(tasks1[i][2]).findNext().getCell(1, 1).getA1Notation()
        sh1.getRange(sh1Tasks1).offset(0, 1).setBackground('#d9ead3')
      }

      if (tasks2[i][0] === 'Y') {
        var sh1Tasks2 = sh1.createTextFinder(tasks2[i][2]).findNext().getCell(1, 1).getA1Notation()
        sh1.getRange(sh1Tasks2).offset(0, 2).setBackground('#d9ead3')
      }

      if (tasks3[i][0] === 'Y') {
        var sh1Tasks3 = sh1.createTextFinder(tasks3[i][2]).findNext().getCell(1, 1).getA1Notation()
        sh1.getRange(sh1Tasks3).offset(0, 3).setBackground('#d9ead3')
      }
      if (tasks4[i][0] === 'Y') {
        var sh1Tasks4 = sh1.createTextFinder(tasks4[i][2]).findNext().getCell(1, 1).getA1Notation()
        sh1.getRange(sh1Tasks4).offset(0, 4).setBackground('#d9ead3')
      }
      if (tasks5[i][0] === 'Y') {
        var sh1Tasks5 = sh1.createTextFinder(tasks5[i][2]).findNext().getCell(1, 1).getA1Notation()
        sh1.getRange(sh1Tasks5).offset(0, 5).setBackground('#d9ead3')
      }
    }
  });
}
```

### Reference:

- [JavaScript Objects](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_objects.asp)
- [map()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_map.asp)
- [filter()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_filter.asp)
- [reduce()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_reduce.asp)
- [match()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_match.asp)

Comment: Feel free to ask any questions related to the answer posted above.

Comment: thank you very much for your effort and kind support. This is working perfectly but in my real spreadsheet, each sh0 sheet represents a client, and each sh0 has sh1. And the number of client sheets are dynamic, each time I gain a client, I add it to the sheet. Is is possible, for example, to apply a forEach loop inside a forEach loop ? For example forEach sh0, apply the action forEach sh1. Is that possible ? If so it is possible to modify the script to this action ? Thank you again for your kind support I highly appreciate it.

Comment: If that is the case, you will only need to determine the value of `sh1` based on the value of `sh0` since the value of `sh0` is already dynamic due to the simple trigger. However, if you have a large amount of `sh0`, you can actually make a list or better yet a [dictionary](https://flexiple.com/javascript/javascript-dictionary) of values to map all pairs of sheets. However you will edit this dictionary manually. Let me try and formulate one example based on the current answer.

Comment: I have just updated the script introducing the use of a JavaScript Object. You may use it as basis for your code. **Please take note that StackOverflow is not a free coding service site.** We can only help you with basic concepts here. With regards to `I also forgot to mention that sh1 also includes the client name. in other words, for every sh1 = "Client Name" sheet, I have a sh0 = "Client Name TDL" sheet. So It may be also possible filter the sheet name ?`, I think this already counts as another question.

Comment: thank you for your effort and response. I am well aware that StackOverflow is not a free coding service. I appreciate the effort. Unfortunately, this will not work because it uses a trigger and my script should run through a button. I also have to plot each new client manually which is not what I am looking for. Thank you again for your efforts, I appreciate it.

Comment: Oh, I did not see that the question was updated. Converting the script to a button based one is simple enough. Let me add a quick fix for that

Comment: Please refer to Script 3

Comment: I have made an edit to the script. It now lists all of the sheets. However it will first get all the sheets with 'TLD' and then store it in an array and then create another array from which it copies the previous one and then remove the 'TLD'. Thus, this script has the assumption that all 'TLD' sheets have a corresponding non-'TLD' sheet.

Comment: hello and thank you for your ongoing support. Is it possible for sh0 to be defined by the TDL sheets instead of the Active sheet ?

Comment: Unfortunately, this will not work because it uses `getActiveSheet()` method. I need to define both `Client Name` sheets and `TDL` sheets.

Comment: So i assune instead of processing one pair of sheets, you want all sheets to be processed with one button, correct? That is actually possible.

Comment: Exactly correct

Comment: Do you have any ideas on how it can be achieved ?

Comment: Yup, please refer to Script 2. The script can now process all sheets with one run. But I am not sure what you meant with `I need to define both "Client" and "Client TDL" sheets`. I guess grouping the sheet names according to TDL and no TDL does the trick?

Comment: First and foremost, I would like to thank you for your very kind and ongoing support. I highly appreciate that you didn't give up on me :) The script is brilliant Patrick, it does exactly what I want it to do. Regarding your question `I guess grouping the sheet names according to TDL and no TDL does the trick? ` Yes this is exactly what I meant and asked for. Thank you again for your time, patience and efforts!

Comment: That is good to hear. I also apologize since it took a while for me to understand what you truly wanted. I realized that the process that you wanted was actually quite simple when you gave more details.

Comment: it took me some time to explain myself correctly, all your answers were rightfully answering the question :) Thank you again for your time and effort!